# Caret Sensurround by circle CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to design my own theme for bootstrap dropdown: I want to have something like below image, I need to show my caret inside of a circle!

[image]

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
<button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mySetting" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
Relative Difference <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
      <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
          <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>    
   </ul>
</div>
```

And this is my .less file for changing colors of drop-down;my question is how can I change the caret in order to have it inside of circle?

```
.btn.mySetting {
  background: #e1e6e4;
  color: #25373e;
}
.btn.mySetting:focus, .btn.mySetting:active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn{
  background: #b2babb !important;
  color: #25373e !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a wrapper for the caret and style it how you want.

Quick example:

```
<div class="caretCircle"><span class="caret"></span></div>

.caretCircle {
    display:inline-block;
    height:1.5em;
    width:1.5em;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

Live example [here](http://www.bootply.com/dwfmZQf9CI).

Comment: The thing is I don't want to set a specific size for it, I want to be responsive  to the text size and button size. I know em is somehow relative size but if I set them to 1 em it shows the circle on top.

Comment: If you want it to be responsive to text size, the only way to do that through just CSS is to use ems. The idea is that you can style this wrapper with any properties you need for the effect that you want. You can also apply CSS to the caret element contained within. It can get as fancy or as light as you want. You never defined any specific criteria for the look, just a general guideline, so I supplied the minimum. Here is a very rough example of a text-size responsive caret that you can adjust positioning/sizes/etc to your needs. http://www.bootply.com/hoAS5Mk4x9